# Get ID of current HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am building firefox plugin. I need to fill the html form, loaded on current webpage, with the help of JSON objects. I have a button on toolbar which will load the javascript code containing JSON objects. but how to retrieve IDs of that loaded html form?

Comment: Do you mean `this.form.id` ?

Comment: Yeah...but I need IDs of all the attributes of loaded form.